# Centering table caption for two-column layout

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, captions, center

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol,lipsum, booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{par}{\par}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{Wijaya}{\hfil\MakeUppercase{#1}\space \Roman{table}}
\DeclareCaptionTextFormat{sc}{{\scshape #1}}
\captionsetup{labelsep=par, labelformat=Wijaya, textformat=sc}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{multicols}
\begin{table}[h!]
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
    \caption{Description of Variables and Parameters} \label{table1}
    \begin{tabular}{cp{5.5cm}}
        \hline
        \midrule[0.1pt]
        Symbol& Parameters\\
        \hline
        $S$&Susceptible subpopulations\\
        $E$&Educated subpopulations\\
        $I$&Infected subpopulations\\
        $R$&Recovered subpopulations\\
        $B$&Bacteria populations\\
        $\Lambda$&Human birth rate\\
        $\mu$&The human natural death rate\\
        $\beta_1$&Interaction rate of susceptible subpopulations with bacteria populations\\
        $\beta_2$&Interaction rate of educated subpopulations with bacteria populations\\
        $k$&Constant saturation rate of the bacteria population\\
        $\omega$&The loss rate of immunity\\
        $\phi$&Educated rate\\
        $\gamma$&The recovery rate of naturally infected populations\\
        $\alpha$&Death rate that caused by cholera infection\\
        $\xi$&The growth rate of bacteria\\
        $\delta$&The natural death rate of bacteria\\
        \hline
        \midrule[0.1pt]
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Why the caption table cannot center in left column? How to fix it?

[image]

**I want**

[image]

Comment: Could you be more precise about what you were expecting? Your table is set outside the `multicols` environment, the caption is centered on the page, the label is slightly moved to the right because of the `\hfil` in the format declaration.

Comment: please see my edited question

Comment: There is a solution, but it will span the entiere page. Is this acceptable?

Comment: Yes, acceptable.

Comment: It is not clear what you after. Your table can be fit in one column. Why you require that it should occupy bot columns? To see, what you doing, please insert `\centering` after `\begin{figure}`.To my opinion (and taste) this gives  very ugly result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some suggestions and comments:

- To typeset the table across the entire width of text block, use a `table*` environment, not a `table` environment.
- To center-set the "Table I" label, replace `\hfil` with `\centering` in the `\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{Wijaya}{...}` directive.
- I would replace the two instance of the old-fashioned `\hline\midrule[0.1pt]` directives with `\toprule` and `\bottomrule`, respectively.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol,lipsum, booktabs, ragged2e,array}

\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{par}{\par}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{Wijaya}{\centering\MakeUppercase{#1}\space \Roman{table}}
\DeclareCaptionTextFormat{sc}{{\scshape #1}}
\captionsetup{labelsep=par, labelformat=Wijaya, textformat=sc}
\begin{document}
%\begin{multicols}{2}
%\lipsum[1-5]
%\end{multicols}
\begin{table*}
\centering
    %\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
    \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
    \caption{Description of Variables and Parameters} \label{table1}
    \begin{tabular}{@{} >{$}c<{$} >{\RaggedRight}p{5.5cm} @{}}
        \toprule
        \mbox{Symbol} &  Parameters\\
        \midrule
        S & Susceptible subpopulations\\
        E & Educated subpopulations\\
        I & Infected subpopulations\\
        R & Recovered subpopulations\\
        B & Bacteria populations\\
        \Lambda & Human birth rate\\
        \mu     & Human natural death rate\\
        \beta_1 & Interaction rate of susceptible subpopulations with bacteria populations\\
        \beta_2 & Interaction rate of educated subpopulations with bacteria populations\\
        k       & Constant saturation rate of the bacteria population\\
        \omega  & Loss rate of immunity\\
        \phi    & Educated rate\\
        \gamma  & Recovery rate of naturally infected populations\\
        \alpha  & Death rate that caused by cholera infection\\
        \xi     & Growth rate of bacteria\\
        \delta  & Natural death rate of bacteria\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

As I mentioned in my comment, it is not clear, what is your problem. Your table can be easy fit in one column, so I would stick with following solution:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article} % <---
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % <---
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}  % <---
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{ % <---
    skip=1ex,
    name=TABLE,
    labelfont={normalsize}, font={footnotesize,sc},
    labelsep=newline,
    justification=centerlast
                    }
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\Roman{table}}  % <---

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}[ht!]
    \centering
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
    \caption{Description of Variables and Parameters} \label{table1}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} >{$}c<{$} X @{}}  % <---
        \toprule
    \text{Symbol}
        &   Parameters                          \\
        \midrule
    S   &   Susceptible subpopulations          \\
    E   &   Educated subpopulations             \\
    I   &   Infected subpopulations             \\
    R   &   Recovered subpopulations            \\
    B   &   Bacteria populations                \\
\Lambda &   Human birth rate                    \\
\mu     &   The human natural death rate        \\
\beta_1 &   Interaction rate of susceptible subpopulations with bacteria populations\\
\beta_2 &   Interaction rate of educated subpopulations with bacteria populations\\
    k   &   Constant saturation rate of the bacteria population\\
\omega  &   The loss rate of immunity           \\
\phi    &   Educated rate                       \\
\gamma  &   The recovery rate of naturally infected populations\\
\alpha  &   Death rate that caused by cholera infection\\
\xi     &   The growth rate of bacteria         \\
\delta  &   The natural death rate of bacteria  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}  % <---
\end{table}
\lipsum[2-6]
\end{document}
```

Note: changes in compasin of your MWE are marked by `<---` above code.

[image]